# What could cause the TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'function' objects?

Tags: python, string, variables, flask, typeerror

I just got the following type error while executing my Python script:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Flask-0.9-py2.7.egg/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/Zach/Dropbox/stock/stk.py", line 31, in stock
url="http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="+stock+"&f=snl1"
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'function' objects
```

The line causing the problem seems to be `url="http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="+stock+"&f=snl1"`, specifically the variable `stock.` After research and from the little I know from previous errors, I deduced that the cause must be an issue with how the variable is defined (it's either not a string, or possibly not defined at all); that said, I define this variable as a string in the function before:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home_search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
            stock = request.form['s']
            return redirect(url_for('stock'))

    return render_template('stk.html')
```

And here is the function, `stock` where I attempt to call and display the value earlier defined:

```
@app.route('/stock', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def stock():
    print type(stock)
    url="http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="+stock+"&f=snl1"
    text=urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

    return render_template('stock.html')
```

However, it is being defined in a different `@app.route` than when I call it. Shouldn't variables in Python be stored and recalled like that, or are variables emptied when new pages are loaded? If this is the case, any suggestions for a work around or a better approach would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Test the type of `stock` to be sure: `type(stock)`

Comment: I'm not an expert in flask, but once you exit the function `home_search()`, `stock` will be garbage collected, plus you can't access it outside of the function anyway.

Comment: i think problem is,, you are treating `stock` as a string in line `return redirect(url_for('stock'))`

Comment: @gecco will the value print in the browser if I say `print type(stock)`?

Comment: @zch: certainly not in the browser since Python runs on server side. It will be logged in the stdout of the server

Comment: @avasal That line is just supposed to load a new `@app.route`, but let me try changing the name of it to avoid a possible mixup

Comment: You seem to be not showing us all the code. The traceback says you're in the function `stock`, not `home_search`.

Comment: @Amber that should be because the snippet at the bottom that I pasted (`home_search`) is where I define `stock` and I then try to call `stock` in the function `stock` later on. I will add that function to my original question.

Comment: @ zch. Give us the type of stock.

Comment: @gecco aha – I now get the error, when trying to print `type(stock)` `global name "stock" is undefined`

Comment: @root I've been testing with `MSFT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Named functions are variables just like everything else. The `stock` that is being used in this line:

```
    url="http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="+stock+"&f=snl1"
```

is the function that contains it. You shouldn't rely on Python variables across requests; instead, you should pass the variable along as a request variable, e.g.

```
/stock?s=whatever
```

and then read it back out of the new `request.form` in the handler for that URL.

---

The `stock` variable that you're creating in your `home_search` function is a local variable that only lives for the life of the call to `home_search`, which ends as soon as you redirect the client to a different URL (such as `/stock`).

Comment: Thank you for your help – that is what I suspected. What is the best way to create a unique referring link?